# double slash when reading

Tags: python, path, xlsx

using this part of the code

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_location):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            df = pd.read_excel(data_location + "\\" + file, usecols=col_list)
            df['File']=file
            df_total = pd.concat([df, df_total], ignore_index=True)
```

is giving this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Users\\bosuna\\
```

As you can see its doubling the "" in the path when it runs.

Comment: it actually looks like an issue with your provided `data_location`

Comment: data_location = r"C:\Users\bosuna\OneDrive\Desktop\pure_b2b\idg\010721\\"

this is what I have in data_location

Comment: please give the full traceback mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the correct file path to `pd.read_excel()`. `data_location` is just the top folder you were searching and `file` is the filename. [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) goes down the folder structure, and passes each folder it's in via the variable you have as `root`. So the following line

```py
df = pd.read_excel(data_location + "\\" + file, usecols=col_list)
```

should be:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(root + "\\" + file, usecols=col_list)
```

or even better:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root, file), usecols=col_list)
```